Robocorp Bot not starting chrome even when chrome.exe is in the path environment variable
I have a robocorp bot in a windows 10 machine. It worked fine but suddenly it stopped working, I think it may be due to a chrome update. Now it won't open google chrome. I am using RPA selenium to open the browser and interact with it. I noticed that the latest chrome version is 127.0.6533.73 and the latest chromedriver version is 127.0.6533.72. I don't know if that affects the compatibility. I am using python 3.10.13 for this project.
This is the error I get when the bot executes:

RPA.Browser.Selenium.BrowserNotFoundError: Failed to start a browser:
Chrome: maximum recursion depth exceeded
Firefox: Could not get browser version
Edge: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

I tried adding the chrome executable to the PATH environment variable to make it available for all the programs but it did not help. I also tried a new clean installation and it did not help either. I don't really know what could be causing this issue since I am very new to RPA and robocorp.
I honestly think that the issue is related to the chromedriver version even though it seems unlikely. I don't understand why this bot suddenly broke and doesn't work anymore.

I finally got it to work again, I created a new clean instance in aws. Next, I added the chrome.exe and chromedriver.exe to the path environment variable. And last I uninstalled google chrome and reinstalled it, I selected the option to delete browsing history, cookies and everything. After that the bot launched chrome
